# Getting department names that have maximum staff count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, one table storing details of staff (columns are staff_id, staff_name, department_id)  and another table storing details of department (columns are department_id, department_name,  department_block_num).

I need to write a query to display names of department that has maximum staff count order by department_name. It is also given that multiple department can also have staff count same as maximum staff count. Another condition is group function is not allowed.

Here is code

```
SELECT department_name
  FROM department
 WHERE department_id IN (SELECT department_id
                           FROM (  SELECT department_id, COUNT (*) AS cnt1
                                     FROM staff
                                    WHERE COUNT (*) =
                                             (SELECT cnt
                                                FROM (  SELECT department_id,
                                                               COUNT (*) AS cnt
                                                          FROM staff
                                                      GROUP BY department_id
                                                      ORDER BY cnt DESC)
                                               WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
                                 GROUP BY department_id));
```

Comment: What is "group function"?  I'm not familiar with any function with that name in Oracle.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment, one that you have not attempted on your own. Try it yourself and see what you can do and learn. Stackoverflow is a great resource for tough problems, but you cant always just turn to it for answers, you need to try get answers on your own

Comment: Max function not allowed. I tried the code but it is saying sql is not ended properly.

Comment: Yes Max function not allowed. Again I want only department names to be displayed which have maximum staff count and there is possibility that more than one department may have same maximum staff count.  Refer to my code please.

Comment: Sir I need to write the sql code without help of max function.  As I need department names maximum staff count, the max function will do the task simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RANK` analytic function to find the rows with the maximum counts:

```
SELECT   department_id,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rnk
FROM     staff
GROUP BY department_id
```

Will rank the rows in order of `DESC`ending count of members of staff and then you can just filter on rows where the rank is 1 (and have the highest count).

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE staff__id__seq;

CREATE TABLE departments (
  id              INT PRIMARY KEY,
  department_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO departments ( id, department_name )
  SELECT 1, 'Aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Ddd' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE staff (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  department_id INT REFERENCES departments( id )
);

INSERT INTO staff ( id, department_id )
SELECT staff__id__seq.NEXTVAL, department_id
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS department_id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2                  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3                  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4                  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
);
```

**Query to count staff**:

```
SELECT   department_id,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rnk
FROM     staff
GROUP BY department_id
```

```
DEPARTMENT_ID | CNT | RNK
------------: | --: | --:
            2 |   5 |   1
            4 |   5 |   1
            1 |   3 |   3
            3 |   2 |   4
```

**Query 2 - Get the department name for the highest counts**:

Just join the previous query to the `departments` table and filter to return the rows when the rank is 1 (the highest count).

```
SELECT d.department_name
FROM   (
         SELECT   department_id,
                  RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rnk
         FROM     staff
         GROUP BY department_id
       ) s
       INNER JOIN departments d
       ON ( d.id = s.department_id )
WHERE  s.rnk = 1
```

**Output**:

```
| DEPARTMENT_NAME |
| :-------------- |
| Bbb             |
| Ddd             |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f379dbf26140815639e2895e905e5936)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid `group by`, then use subqueries:

```
select d.*,
       (select count(*)
        from staff s
        where s.department_id = d.department_id
       ) as staff_cnt
from department d;
```

If you then want the top departments, with ties, use subqueries and window functions:

```
select . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from (select d.*,
           rank() over (order by staff_cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (select d.*,
                   (select count(*)
                    from staff s
                    where s.department_id = d.department_id
                   ) as staff_cnt
            from department d
           ) d
      ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is homework or similar and that windows function are not allowed here is a solution using more basic sql

```
SELECT department_name
FROM department d
JOIN staff s ON d.department_id = s.department_id
GROUP BY department_name
HAVING COUNT(s.department_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) as stat 
    FROM staff 
    GROUP BY department_id 
    ORDER BY stat DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
ORDER BY department_name
```